# Get value from variable instead of command line in argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse, pynetdicom

I am using pynetdicom script to fetch the data from the dcm4chee.
to run the script I need to pass the arguments from the command line. 
But I already have that value in some variable or in other object and I need to use from there but I am not getting how can I pass that value to the parser or Is it possible to do without parsing.

Please help me to know how can I pass the value using some variables instead of passing through the command line.

**Script :**

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

"""
For help on usage, 
python qrscu.py -h 

"""

import argparse
from netdicom.applicationentity import AE
from netdicom.SOPclass import *
from dicom.dataset import Dataset, FileDataset
from dicom.UID import ExplicitVRLittleEndian, ImplicitVRLittleEndian, ExplicitVRBigEndian
import netdicom
import tempfile

# parse commandline
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='storage SCU example')
print "parser", parser
parser.add_argument('remotehost')
parser.add_argument('remoteport', type=int)
parser.add_argument('searchstring')
parser.add_argument('-p', help='local server port', type=int, default=9999)
parser.add_argument('-aet', help='calling AE title', default='PYNETDICOM')
parser.add_argument('-aec', help='called AE title', default='REMOTESCU')
parser.add_argument('-implicit', action='store_true', help='negociate implicit transfer syntax only', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-explicit', action='store_true', help='negociate explicit transfer syntax only', default=False)

args = parser.parse_args()
print "args :::: ", type(args), args

if args.implicit:
    ts = [ImplicitVRLittleEndian]
elif args.explicit:
    ts = [ExplicitVRLittleEndian]
else:
    ts = [
        ExplicitVRLittleEndian, 
        ImplicitVRLittleEndian, 
        ExplicitVRBigEndian
        ]

# call back
def OnAssociateResponse(association):
    print "Association response received"


def OnAssociateRequest(association):
    print "Association resquested"
    return True

def OnReceiveStore(SOPClass, DS):
    print "Received C-STORE", DS.PatientName
    try:
        # do something with dataset. For instance, store it.
        file_meta = Dataset()
        file_meta.MediaStorageSOPClassUID = '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2'
        file_meta.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID = "1.2.3"  # !! Need valid UID here
        file_meta.ImplementationClassUID = "1.2.3.4"  # !!! Need valid UIDs here
        filename = '%s/%s.dcm' % (tempfile.gettempdir(), DS.SOPInstanceUID)
        ds = FileDataset(filename, {}, file_meta=file_meta, preamble="\0" * 128)
        ds.update(DS)
        ds.save_as(filename)
        print "File %s written" % filename
    except:
        pass
    # must return appropriate status
    return SOPClass.Success

# create application entity with Find and Move SOP classes as SCU and
# Storage SOP class as SCP
MyAE = AE(args.aet, args.p, [PatientRootFindSOPClass,
                             PatientRootMoveSOPClass,
                             VerificationSOPClass], [StorageSOPClass], ts)
MyAE.OnAssociateResponse = OnAssociateResponse
MyAE.OnAssociateRequest = OnAssociateRequest
MyAE.OnReceiveStore = OnReceiveStore
MyAE.start()


# remote application entity
RemoteAE = dict(Address=args.remotehost, Port=args.remoteport, AET=args.aec)

# create association with remote AE
print "Request association"
assoc = MyAE.RequestAssociation(RemoteAE)

# perform a DICOM ECHO
print "DICOM Echo ... ",
if assoc:
    st = assoc.VerificationSOPClass.SCU(1)
    print 'done with status "%s"' % st

    print "DICOM FindSCU ... ",
    print "\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    d = Dataset()
    d.StudyDate = args.searchstring
    d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "STUDY"
    d.PatientID = "*"
    study = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]
    print 'done with status "%s"' % st
    print "\n\n\n Cont...", study
    print "\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    # loop on patients
    for pp in study:
        print "\n\n----------------------Pateint Detals------------------------------------------------\n\n"
        print "%s - %s" % (pp.StudyDate, pp.PatientID)
        # find studies
        d = Dataset()
        d.PatientID = pp.PatientID
        d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "STUDY"
        d.PatientName = ""
        d.StudyInstanceUID = ""
        d.StudyDate = ""
        d.StudyTime = ""
        d.StudyID = ""
        d.ModalitiesInStudy = ""
        d.StudyDescription = ""
        studies = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]
        # loop on studies
        for st in studies:
            print "\n study :: ", studies
            print "\n\n---------------------------Study---------------------------\n\n"
            print "    %s - %s %s" % (st.StudyDescription, st.StudyDate, st.StudyTime)
            d = Dataset()
            d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "SERIES"
            d.StudyInstanceUID = st.StudyInstanceUID
            d.SeriesInstanceUID = ""
            d.InstanceNumber = ""
            d.Modality = ""
            d.SeriesNumber = ""
            d.SeriesDescription = ""
            d.AccessionNumber = ""
            d.SeriesDate = ""
            d.SeriesTime = ""
            d.SeriesID = ""
            d.NumberOfSeriesRelatedInstances = ""
            series = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]

            # print series uid and number of instances
            if series:
                for se in series:
                    print "\n\n---------------------------Series---------------------------\n\n"
                    print "\n\n\n series", se
                    print " %15s - %10s - %35s - %5s" % (se.SeriesNumber, se.Modality, se.SeriesDescription, se.NumberOfSeriesRelatedInstances)

    print "Release association"
    assoc.Release(0)

    # done
    MyAE.Quit()
else:
    print "Failed to create Association."

# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

Comment: You have a program _program1.py_ with some data in _variable1_ and you want to use _qrscu.py_ program with _variable1_ as parameter?

Comment: put everything inside functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put everything inside functions and call them wherever you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
For help on usage, 
python qrscu.py -h 

"""
import os
import argparse
from netdicom.applicationentity import AE
from netdicom.SOPclass import *
from dicom.dataset import Dataset, FileDataset
from dicom.UID import ExplicitVRLittleEndian, ImplicitVRLittleEndian, ExplicitVRBigEndian
import netdicom
import tempfile

# call back
def OnAssociateResponse(association):
    print "Association response received"

def OnAssociateRequest(association):
    print "Association resquested"
    return True

def OnReceiveStore(SOPClass, DS):
    print "Received C-STORE", DS.PatientName
    try:
        # do something with dataset. For instance, store it.
        file_meta = Dataset()
        file_meta.MediaStorageSOPClassUID = '1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2'
        file_meta.MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID = "1.2.3"  # !! Need valid UID here
        file_meta.ImplementationClassUID = "1.2.3.4"  # !!! Need valid UIDs here
        filename = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), DS.SOPInstanceUID + '%s.dcm')
        ds = FileDataset(filename, {}, file_meta=file_meta, preamble="\0" * 128)
        ds.update(DS)
        ds.save_as(filename)
        print "File %s written" % filename
    except Exception as e:
        print "Some exception occured", e 
    # must return appropriate status
    return SOPClass.Success

def print_data(remotehost, remoteport, searchstring, local_port=9999,
        calling_title='PYNETDICOM', called_title='REMOTESCU',
        ts=(ExplicitVRLittleEndian, ImplicitVRLittleEndian, ExplicitVRBigEndian)):
    # create application entity with Find and Move SOP classes as SCU and
    # Storage SOP class as SCP
    MyAE = AE(calling_title, local_port, [PatientRootFindSOPClass,
                                PatientRootMoveSOPClass,
                                VerificationSOPClass], [StorageSOPClass], ts)
    MyAE.OnAssociateResponse = OnAssociateResponse
    MyAE.OnAssociateRequest = OnAssociateRequest
    MyAE.OnReceiveStore = OnReceiveStore
    MyAE.start()

    # remote application entity
    RemoteAE = dict(Address=remotehost, Port=remoteport, AET=called_title)

    # create association with remote AE
    print "Request association"
    assoc = MyAE.RequestAssociation(RemoteAE)

    # perform a DICOM ECHO
    print "DICOM Echo ... ",
    if not assoc:
        print "Failed to create Association."
        return

    st = assoc.VerificationSOPClass.SCU(1)
    print 'done with status "%s"' % st

    print "DICOM FindSCU ... ",
    print "\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    d = Dataset()
    d.StudyDate = searchstring
    d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "STUDY"
    d.PatientID = "*"
    study = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]
    print 'done with status "%s"' % st
    print "\n\n\n Cont...", study
    print "\n\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    # loop on patients
    for pp in study:
        print "\n\n----------------------Pateint Detals------------------------------------------------\n\n"
        print "%s - %s" % (pp.StudyDate, pp.PatientID)
        # find studies
        d = Dataset()
        d.PatientID = pp.PatientID
        d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "STUDY"
        d.PatientName = ""
        d.StudyInstanceUID = ""
        d.StudyDate = ""
        d.StudyTime = ""
        d.StudyID = ""
        d.ModalitiesInStudy = ""
        d.StudyDescription = ""
        studies = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]
        # loop on studies
        for st in studies:
            print "\n study :: ", studies
            print "\n\n---------------------------Study---------------------------\n\n"
            print "    %s - %s %s" % (st.StudyDescription, st.StudyDate, st.StudyTime)
            d = Dataset()
            d.QueryRetrieveLevel = "SERIES"
            d.StudyInstanceUID = st.StudyInstanceUID
            d.SeriesInstanceUID = ""
            d.InstanceNumber = ""
            d.Modality = ""
            d.SeriesNumber = ""
            d.SeriesDescription = ""
            d.AccessionNumber = ""
            d.SeriesDate = ""
            d.SeriesTime = ""
            d.SeriesID = ""
            d.NumberOfSeriesRelatedInstances = ""
            series = [x[1] for x in assoc.PatientRootFindSOPClass.SCU(d, 1)][:-1]

            # print series uid and number of instances
            for se in series:
                print "\n\n---------------------------Series---------------------------\n\n"
                print "\n\n\n series", se
                print " %15s - %10s - %35s - %5s" % (se.SeriesNumber, se.Modality, se.SeriesDescription, se.NumberOfSeriesRelatedInstances)

    print "Release association"
    assoc.Release(0)

    # done
    MyAE.Quit()

def parse_commandline():
    # parse commandline
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='storage SCU example')
    print "parser", parser
    parser.add_argument('remotehost')
    parser.add_argument('remoteport', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('searchstring')
    parser.add_argument('-p', help='local server port', type=int, default=9999)
    parser.add_argument('-aet', help='calling AE title', default='PYNETDICOM')
    parser.add_argument('-aec', help='called AE title', default='REMOTESCU')
    parser.add_argument('-implicit', action='store_true', help='negociate implicit transfer syntax only', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-explicit', action='store_true', help='negociate explicit transfer syntax only', default=False)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print "args :::: ", type(args), args

    if args.implicit:
        ts = [ImplicitVRLittleEndian]
    elif args.explicit:
        ts = [ExplicitVRLittleEndian]
    else:
        ts = [
            ExplicitVRLittleEndian, 
            ImplicitVRLittleEndian, 
            ExplicitVRBigEndian
            ]
    return args, ts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args, ts = parse_commandline()
    print_data(args.remotehost, args.remoteport, args.searchstring, args.p, args.aet, args.aec, ts)
```

and use it like:

```
import your_module
your_module.print_data(remotehost, remoteport, searchstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate and use the script above in your own code by using the pyhton module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html). It will let you run the script with arguments that you define depending on your variables or objects.

Example: Let say that you have some variables your_arg_1...your_arg_n that can be consumed by grscu.py. Then you can pass these variables to the script with

```
 import subprocess
 r = subprocess.check_call(['grscu.py', your_arg_1, your_arg_2, ..., your_arg_n])
```

The "args = parser.parse_args()" in the script will grab the variables and pass them to the MyAE object. For more information about argparse, see [link](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).